# RegEx match single character that is not follow by a character

Tags: regex

I have a Regex that is almost what I need. I am sure this is a repeat of a repeat however I can't find the answer I am looking for.

Regex I need is an expression that will match a parenthesis that is not followed by a space, however I only want it to match the parenthesis.

```
(\([^\s])
```

This will match all parenthesis that are not followed by a space, however it matches the character that is directly after the parenthesis as well. 
How do I only get a match for the parenthesis?

Comment: just put parenthesis in your regex before like this (\\()[^\s]

Comment: Will a parenthesis ever be the last character of the string/line? I ask because "not followed by a space" and "followed by a character that's not a space" are not the same thing. Positive lookaheads like `(?=\S)` must match a `\S` character, whereas negative lookaheads like `(?!\s)` would also match a _lack_ of any character.

Comment: I am trying to clean up some PHP code by putting spaces between all opening parenthesis and the contents, but if the the parenthesis already has a space after it I don't want to add another space to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [zero width assertion lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

```
\((?=\S)
```

or

```
\((?=[^\s])
```